# (JQuery) Saving page state throughout history

Tags: jquery, history, state, save

I have a page with a movie list, which extends as soon as you scroll down. When I click one of these movies to see the details, and after that hit the back button in my browser, it forgot the state it was in. It returns me back at the top of the page without any extended movies I saw earlier.

I've been searching but couldn't find the right answers. What should I do to make it remember the state it is in? I know it's probably something with hashtags? I would prefer to keep it as minimal as possible since I already took care of the loading of the pages inside the current page. But if it really requires a plugin it's not a problem.

Comment: check out http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html its quite a piece of work, and doesn't even work in many browsers at the time being, but it sure is awesome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ben Alman’s BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) does that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ben Alman's hash change [plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: I have no clue on how I should implement this to my click function (which is launched when I scroll to the bottom). See my next comment for the function.

Comment: `$('#navigatie a').live('click', function(){
 var pagina = $(this).attr('href');
 var aantalResultaten = $('#resultaten .aantalResultaten').text();
 var $aantalZien = $('#resultaten .aantalZien');

 $('<div>').load(pagina + ' #content', function(){
  $('#subPaginaLoader').remove();
  $('#navigatie').before($(this).find('div.film, div#navigatie, div.paginaEinde').outerHTML()).remove();
  if((parseFloat($aantalZien.text())+10) >= aantalResultaten){
   $aantalZien.text(aantalResultaten);
  }
  else{
   $aantalZien.text(parseFloat($aantalZien.text())+10);
  }

 });
 return false;
});`

Comment: Horrible markup. I'm not sure how and where to continue my questions on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I think the BBQ plugin comes closer to what I want so I'll accept the other comment as the answer. But because I have no clue on how to implement it, I will start a new question about it.